# How to remove auto generated log files

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working on laravel project where few folders and files are auto-generated

As my project is on server, there are few files generated there and when I am trying to delete project (as I no longer required it), it removed all files expecting this auto-generated files and folder.

Is there anyway to delete it from server? I know with master credentials it would be possible, but with my current credentials is there anyway to do this?

[image]

Comment: `sudo rm -rf storage`, assuming you're a sudoer user

Comment: why delete the whole storage folder ?

Comment: @khan As I mentioned in my question, I no longer need that project on my server

Comment: @MarkBaker, I have tried with that, but I don't have sudo password so not able to move ahead

Comment: The files will be owned by the webserver account; but unless you knock up a little script that can be run from the webserver to delete them, you'll need sudo permissions to do so

Comment: The file are created by the www-data and owned by www-data group to.
Just create a PHP script which will remove all the files from these directories. Since PHP is run with www-data user.
Something like. $files = glob(storage_path('framework/cache').'/*'); then loop on $files and unlink them